# How do i parse this array?

Tags: php, arrays, list

This is a simplify version. I have an array $collected_data with the values

```
Array
(
    [id] => 10711
    [log_id] => 892
    [form_id] => 2
    [value] => fname
)
Array
(
    [id] => 10712
    [log_id] => 892
    [form_id] => 3
    [value] => lastname
)
Array
(
    [id] => 10717
    [log_id] => 892
    [form_id] => 8
    [value] => email
)
// ...
// etc
```

How can I have a output like:

```
fname lastname | email
fname lastname | email
etc
```

I tried:

```
foreach($form_data as $form_field)
{
    $collected_data_sql = "SELECT * FROM `".WPSC_TABLE_SUBMITED_FORM_DATA."` WHERE `log_id` = '".$purchase['id']."' AND `form_id` = '".$form_field['id']."' LIMIT 1";
    $collected_data = $wpdb->get_results($collected_data_sql,ARRAY_A);

    $collected_data = $collected_data[0];

    list($fname, $lastname, $email) = $collected_data;

    echo $fname. ' '.$lastname.' | '.$email;
}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but why not do a JOIN rather that calling that query so many times?

Comment: *that didn't work* - What was your output instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manual if you're using a function you're not totally clear about. [`list`](http://php.net/list) expects an array with 0-based numeric indexes. You can convert an array from string keys to numeric ones with [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
list($fname, $lastname, $email) = array_values($collected_data);
```

(in case that was your issue, I'm not so sure because your question does not give much information about your concrete problem)

Additionally you have an array of an array, so you need to extract the data you're interested in as well, e.g.:

```
$fname = $fname['value'];
$lastname= $lastname['value'];
$email = $email['value'];
```

But that's just exemplary.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take into account the array indices in your `$collected_data`, so list() won't work. That would only work if you had `array('John', 'Smith', 'john.smith@example.com');`

You will need to iterate through the results and pull out the value from the 'value' key.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you echo out your $collected_data_sql, and test on an IDE to see if your SQL is correct first. I believe your error started there within your where conditions.